# How to write a htaccess file to directory from wildcard subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I am creating dynamic (wildcard) sub-domains using .htaccess like so:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.php?n=%1&v=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com/why/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/ [QSA,L]
```

When a directory is included in the URI, e.g. dynamic.domain.com/directory the URL changes to the "real" subdomain like so: subdomain.domain.com/directory/

My question is how the keep the URL from showing the actual subdomain.

xyz.domain.com works as expected

xyz.domain.com/dir will change the URL to dynamic.domain.com/dir which should be xyz.domain.com/dir